# ubuntu 13.04 64bit on pentium 4, 2 GHz with 2 GB RAM

Tags: 13.04

please advice can i run ubuntu 13.04 64bit  on Pentium 4 cpu of  2 Ghz clock, 2GB RAM with nvidia 210 GPU with 1 GB ram.

Answer (score 0):

You have not provided enough information on your processor to determine whether it is of 64 or 32-bit. If you are already running Windows, try this link [here](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001121.htm)

If your pentium cpu is indeed a 64-bit cpu, you can safely go on to installing a 64-bit flavour of Ubuntu; otherwise, stay with the 32-bit version.